# Database design linked list vs. order by

Tags: sql-server, database, database-schema

I have a table which need to persist some user actions in sequence. I can either save it by using a self reference table which will be like a linked list or not using the self reference at all and just use the times tamp to keep the sequence.
This table has reference to other tables such as user and files associated with an action.
The operations will need support CRUD. The frequency of operations are in this order: Retrieve > Insert > Update > Delete

What is your design preference and why?
Thanks!

Comment: "The most frequent operations are Retrieve > Insert > Update > Delete"... ummmm...

Comment: can someone explain this cryptic comment?  is there something in that ordering that is impossible?

Comment: @AndrewCooke The original wording seemed simply to be a list of the frequent operations, not in order. Yet is was all the operations. It seems obvious what was meant *now*, but it didn't before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i would avoid "linked lists" like the plague.  about the only thing they are good for is retrieving the "next" item.  the problem is that every extra "hop" requires a join, so if you want to parameterise over that (eg to provide a function that retrieves `N` items following a given item) then you need one of (1) machine-generated joins (2) multiple selects (3) SQL that's unlikely to be portable and/or supported by your ORM.

this is the same problem that makes trees notoriously nasty in sql.  it's "fixed" by recursive joins, but that's (3) above (maybe i am old-fashioned and someone will say that these are well supported now - if so i guess i will learn...).

Comment: Well articulated. All three points are well worth up vote. Like to hear more opinions but this is a great one!

Comment: I would disagree with the argument that you need multiple selects or  generated SQL.  Syntactically, these structures are now well supported with recursive joins.  That said, I think `order by` offers superior performance for most workloads.